# Get blank data from API even data is available for fetch in database

Tags: php, laravel, database, controller

I am working on laravel project and in this project I have make two API one is working perfectly like I am getting all the data from database accurately but in the second API I am getting blank data means nothing both API is same but just from one API am getting data from ID and in second API I am getting data from email. Please help me.

It is my api.php code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    
    return $request->user();
});
// routes/api.php
// POST /api/post?api_token=UNIQUE_TOKEN
Route::post('post', 'Api\PostController@store')->middleware('auth:api');
Route::get('/getemail/"{email}"','EmailController@databyemail');


and it's my EmailController Code

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\email;

class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function databyemail($email){
        
    $data = new email();
    
    $data = email::find($email);
    
    return response()->json($data);
}}
and finally it is my email model code

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class email extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['surname','first_name','last_name','username','email','password','language','contact_no','address','remember_token','business_id','status'];
}
```

Please help me why I am getting nothing from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should fix your Route, you don't need to use " " marks for the variables.

```
Route::get('/getemail/{email}','EmailController@databyemail');
```

Just use like this.

Also, find works with Primary key so,

Instead of:

`$data = email::find($email);`

Use:

`$data = email::where('email', $email)->first();`

Comment: $data = email::find($email);
You are using $email for find, you can only use Primary Key in find,
instead use,
`$data = email::firstWhere('email', $email);`

Comment: dear when i write $data = email::firstWhere('email', $email); and remove $data = email::find($email); so i am getting error of 500

Comment: Then try,
`$data = email::where('email', $email)->first();`

Comment: Thank you dear it's working like a charm thank you so much you made my day

Comment: well i have one more query regarding this question can you answer me on this or i need to create new question

Comment: dear can you help me if i want to get email address with password i mean i want where email and password is

Comment: Can you explain your issue a bit more?

Comment: actully i want to fetch data by email and password how can i do it in this api

Comment: First, you should use POST method, when you are using confidential information,
secondly,
you can do it as per below,

`public function databyemail(Request $request){

    $data = email::where('email', $request->email)->first();
   if($data->password === bcrypt($request->password)) {
    return response()->json($data);
   } else {
     return response()->json(['error' => 'Incorrect credentials!']);
   } 
}}`

bcrypt is hash encryption, Laravel use, if you have stored without it, you can directly compare it. But for safety password should never be used in query directly so.

Comment: but how can i use password in it

Comment: And your route will be like

`Route::post('/getemail','EmailController@databyemail');`

Comment: what should i write on browser to fetch data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207589/discussion-between-hiren-faldu-and-digi-soft).